# Datagridview with linq to entities anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am struggling to understand how to update an SQL database from a datagridview that has been filled with a linq query using linq to entities.

I pull in data from three tables; Items, Missions and linkMissionItem with the following query:

```
var itemList = from x in me.LinkMissionItem
    join i in me.items on x.itemID equals i.itemID
    join m in me.Missions on x.missionID equals m.MissionID
    where m.MissionNo == selectedMission
    orderby i.categoryID, i.name
    select new { i.itemID, 
                 i.name, 
                 x.Role, 
                 i.Type.typeName, 
                 i.Category.categoryName, 
                 i.model, 
                 i.serialNo, 
                 i.Origin.originCountry, 
                 i.cost, 
                 x.Packaging };
```

I understand that the query gives an anonymous type pulling in some columns from all three tables and binding it to a datagridview like so:

```
dgvMissionItems.DataSource = itemList.ToList();
```

making the datagridview read only. Incidently, I currently update the Packaging field programatically, no problem.

But the great thing about having a datagridview is to add or change data in it by editing the individual cell(s). I need to allow the user to edit the Role field from the linkMissionItem table. If I fill a datagridview with only the entity LinkMissionTable (making it modifyable) the information for the user is unfriendly and unclear.

I have misunderstood or am attacking this problem perhaps in the wrong way and am in desperate need of some advice on how to get the job done. I haven't as yet been able to find anything on the Internet or in the books I have on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should retrieve the whole entity (along with the related entities required) but disable the `AutoGenerateColumns` feature of the DataGridView. Then only define the columns you want to show the user instead of breaking the link between the entities and the datasource of the grid by repackaging them into new objects.

Comment: Thank you dutzu for your help, I have retrieved all the items from the entity and some from the other two entities. 
            DataGridViewColumn colRole = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            etc..
            colRole.ReadOnly = false;
            dgvMissionItems.Columns.Add(colRole);
but I still cannot edit. What do you mean by ”instead of breaking the link between the entities and the datasource of the grid by repackaging them into new objects I tried List<Object> tempList = new List<Object>() and added the annonymous type entries but still no luck. Cannot edit the column.

Comment: NOOOO, don't use the new anonymous class. Return the entities as-is and give them to the DataGrid. Don't create new objects, return the entities as they are in the db, and only show the columns with the properties that you want to show. That way you should still have the edit functionality.

Comment: OPPS sorry, understood. One last thing though if you don't mind, if I use the "into" in the query combining the joins, is this a good solution?

Comment: it should work, just return the entities and not new objects.