# how to binding gridview with data from two different tables C#

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, binding

How can I binding gridview with data from two different tables? I have three tables: Players, PlayerTeam and Teams. My gridview has next data: PlayerID, Name, Surname, ... from table Players, and TeamID, TeamName... from another table Teams. Table PlayerTeam marge tables Players and Teams via IDs.  I'am using tableAdapter to solve this problem.

When I want to edit some row in gridview, I make changes in form (change data in textbox) and select Team from dropdownlist, but I can't save this changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Rukomet
{
    public partial class IgracUI : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        dsIgrac.tblIgracRow igrac;
        dsKlub.tblKlubRow klub;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsPostBack)
                return;
            this.UcitajKlub();
            this.dohvatiIgraca();
            this.prikaziIgracevePodatke();

        }

        private void pokupiPodatkeSForme()
        {
            this.igrac.MaticniBroj = this.txtMaticniBroj.Text;
            this.igrac.Ime = this.txtIme.Text;
            this.igrac.Prezime = this.txtPrezime.Text;
            this.igrac.BrojDresa = this.txtBrojDresa.Text;
            this.igrac.Pogoci = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtPogoci.Text);
            this.igrac.Opomene = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtOpomene.Text);
            this.igrac.DvijeMinute = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtDvijeMinute.Text);
            this.igrac.Diskvalifikacija = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtDiskvalifikacija.Text);

            this.igrac.Lijecnicki = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtLijecnicki.Text);

            this.klub.KlubID = Convert.ToInt32(this.ddlKlubovi.SelectedValue);

        }

        private void prikaziIgracevePodatke()
        {
            if (igrac.IgracID == -1)
                return;

            this.txtMaticniBroj.Text = igrac.MaticniBroj;
            this.txtIme.Text = igrac.Ime;
            this.txtPrezime.Text = igrac.Prezime;
            this.txtBrojDresa.Text = igrac.BrojDresa;
            this.txtPogoci.Text = igrac.Pogoci.ToString();
            this.txtOpomene.Text = igrac.Opomene.ToString();
            this.txtDvijeMinute.Text = igrac.DvijeMinute.ToString();
            this.txtDiskvalifikacija.Text = igrac.Diskvalifikacija.ToString();

            this.txtLijecnicki.Text = igrac.Lijecnicki.ToShortDateString();


            if (this.ViewState["selected"] != null)
            {
                ddlKlubovi.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(this.ViewState["selected"]);
            }

        }

        private void dohvatiIgraca()
        {
            dsIgrac.tblIgracDataTable tblIgrac = new dsIgrac.tblIgracDataTable();

            if (Request.Params["IgracID"] == null)
            {
                this.igrac = tblIgrac.NewtblIgracRow();
                this.igrac.IgracID = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                dsIgracTableAdapters.tblIgracTableAdapter adapterIgrac = new dsIgracTableAdapters.tblIgracTableAdapter();

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(this.Request.Params["IgracID"]);

                adapterIgrac.FillByIgracID(tblIgrac, id);

                this.igrac = (dsIgrac.tblIgracRow)tblIgrac.Rows[0];
            }
        }


        void UcitajKlub()
        {
            dsIgrac.tblKlubDataTable Klub = new dsIgrac.tblKlubDataTable();

            dsIgracTableAdapters.tblKlubTableAdapter adapterKlub = new dsIgracTableAdapters.tblKlubTableAdapter();

            adapterKlub.Fill(Klub);
            this.ddlKlubovi.DataTextField = "ImeKluba";
            this.ddlKlubovi.DataValueField = "KlubID";

            this.ddlKlubovi.DataSource = Klub;
            this.ddlKlubovi.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnOdustani_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Response.Redirect("GlavnaForma.aspx");
        }


        protected void btnSpremi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.dohvatiIgraca();
            this.pokupiPodatkeSForme();

            dsIgracTableAdapters.tblIgracTableAdapter adapterIgrac = new dsIgracTableAdapters.tblIgracTableAdapter();


            if (this.igrac.IgracID == -1)
            {
                adapterIgrac.Insert(
                    this.igrac.MaticniBroj,
                    this.igrac.Ime,
                    this.igrac.Prezime,
                    this.igrac.BrojDresa,
                    this.igrac.Pogoci,
                    this.igrac.Opomene,
                    this.igrac.DvijeMinute,
                    this.igrac.Diskvalifikacija,
                    this.igrac.Lijecnicki);
                    this.klub.KlubID);

            }
            else
            {
                adapterIgrac.Update(this.igrac);
            }
            this.Response.Redirect("GlavnaForma.aspx");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post code for a better answer but I think I understand what you are asking. To accomplish this I use a C# WebGrid in HTML that queries three tables like this:

```
@{
var db=Database.Open("Contracts");
var selectCommand = "SELECT Requests.*, Contractors.Agency+'/'"+
                    "+Contractors.FirstName+' '+Contractors.LastName as Contractor,Programs.Division "+
                    "FROM Requests, Contractors, Programs "+
                    "WHERE ContractNumber is not null "+
                    "and ContractNumber <> '' "+
                    "and ScannedContractDate is not null "+
                    "and AmendmentCount = 0 "+
                    "and Contractors.id = Requests.ContractorId "+
                    "and Requests.programId = Programs.Id "; 
}
<h2>Page Title</h2>
<div>@grid.GetHtml( tableStyle: "grid",
            headerStyle: "head",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Division"),
            grid.Column("ContractNumber", header:"Contract Number"),
            grid.Column("Contractor"),
            grid.Column("StartDate", header:"Start Date", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("EndDate", header:"End Date", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("Amount"),
            grid.Column("ScannedContractDate", header:"Contract Date", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("MaxAmend", header:"Amendments")
           ) ) 
        </div>
```

I hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a join or group clause and bind the result to the said data grid view.

Refer to the following links:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106406/datagridview-with-linq-to-entities-anonymous-type)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393223/binding-linq-query-to-datagridview)